# For each ID, count the instances where one value is contained, the instances where another is contained, and another where both are contained dplyr

Tags: r

I have a dataset with many ID variables. I would like to count the number of ID variables that have data for "day", "night", and both.

| ID | Time of Day |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | day |
| 1 | night |
| 2 | night |
| 3 | day |
| 4 | day |
| 4 | night |

I need to know the number of IDs that just have day, just have night, and have both. Here, one ID has just night, 1 has just day, and 2 have both. I wanted to do something like:

```
df %>% filter(`Time of Day` == "Day") %>% summarize(count = n())
```

but this obviously will count the number of times "day" shows up, not the number of IDs that just have "day".

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4), time = c("day", "night", 
"night", "day", "day", "night")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: It seems like `table(df)` is the place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- structure(list(
  id = c("id1", "id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id4"),
  time = c("day", "night", "night", "day", "day", "night")),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

tab <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))
tab
#>     day night
#> id1   1     1
#> id2   0     1
#> id3   1     0
#> id4   1     1

onlyday <- nrow(tab[tab$day > 0 & tab$night == 0,])
onlynight <- nrow(tab[tab$day == 0 & tab$night > 0,])
both <- nrow(tab[tab$day > 0 & tab$night > 0,])

cbind(onlyday, onlynight, both)
#>      onlyday onlynight both
#> [1,]       1         1    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using dplyr. This code groups observations into those which have only days, only night, or both days and nights. You  can get the number of IDs which satisfy one of these with `now()` on the appropriate data.

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5),
                time_of_day = c("day", "day", "night", "day", "day", "night", "day", "night"))
```

Which is:

```
  ID time_of_day
1  1         day
2  1         day
3  2       night
4  3         day
5  4         day
6  4       night
7  5         day
8  5       night
```

Create a `%notin%`:

```
`%notin%` = Negate(`%in%`)
```

Then:

```
days = df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter((time_of_day == "day") & ("night" %notin% time_of_day)) %>%
  summarise(count = n())

nights = df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter((time_of_day == "night") & ("day" %notin% time_of_day)) %>%
summarise(count = n())

both = df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter("day" %in% time_of_day & "night" %in% time_of_day) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

`days`

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     ID count
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     2
2     3     1
```

`nights`

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
     ID count
  <dbl> <int>
1     2     1
```

`both`

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
     ID count
  <dbl> <int>
1     4     2
2     5     2
```

Edit: The `&&` in the original answer should be `&`.

Comment: Can you replace `filter((time_of_day == "night") && ("day" %notin% time_of_day))` with `filter(time_of_day == "night") && (time_of_day != "day"))` in dplyr?

Comment: Since `!=` is testing inequality, that expression will test whether each value is equal to  "night" and not equal to "day", which will always be true if the value is "night". The `%notin%` is testing whether "day" is contained in the vector that was grouped by ID. That way if a given ID contains both "day" and "night" the second expression will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd like to try something like this. First code each `id` as all day, all night, or both. Then `summarise` and `sum` up number the number of id's for each of these three conditions.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(
    all_day = sum(all(time == "day")),
    all_night = sum(all(time == "night")),
    both = sum(all(c("day", "night") %in% time))
  ) %>%
  summarise(across(-id, sum))
```

**Output**

```
  all_day all_night  both
    <int>     <int> <int>
1       1         1     2
```